# Vertically align an image next to paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image that is usually shorter in height than the adjacent paragraph to vertically align in the middle and just can't do it

```
<div class="element">
    <img  src="http://dummyimage.com/75" />
    <p  class="text" >Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>Blah Blah<br/>
    </p>
```

Here's my css so far

```
.element{display:table;height:100%}
.text{display:table-cell;background:#CC0;padding:20px;}
.element img{display:table-cell;margin-right:10px;vertical-align:middle;}
```

And a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0krndsav/

Most other questions want the paragraph in the vertical middle of an image...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` for `vertical-align`.

CSS

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="church-admin-calendar-widget-item">
  <img width="75" height="60" src="http://dummyimage.com/75" />
  <div class="content-holder">
    <p  class="ca_event_detail" >
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
      Blah Blah<br/>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sq76xoak/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your `.element` :

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

[Here is your jsFiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/0krndsav/5/)

Comment: IE9 and lower don't support this property

Comment: IE9 ? :D please.. Netscape doesn't support it neither. It is simple css3 specs, let's ignore fake browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `div` container for your `img` and apply there `table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
.church-admin-calendar-widget-item {
    display:table;
}
.ca_event_detail {
    display:table-cell;
    background:#CC0
}
img {   
    margin-right:10px;
}

#imgCont{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="church-admin-calendar-widget-item">
    <div id="imgCont">
        <img width="75" height="60" src="http://dummyimage.com/75" />
    </div>
    <p class="ca_event_detail">Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>Blah Blah
        <br/>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0krndsav/6/)**

Simply use this;

```
img, p
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.ca_event_detail {

  background: #CC0;

  width: 100px;

  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: middle;

}

img {

  margin-right: 10px;

  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<div class="church-admin-calendar-widget-item">
  <img width="75" height="60" src="http://dummyimage.com/75" />
  <p class="ca_event_detail">Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>Blah Blah
    <br/>
  </p>
</div>
```